# JDialog, Error display Query?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have Class which extends `JDialog`.

Have an another JDialog declared inside the class as

```
private JDialog Dialog = new JDialog(this);
```

I want to display a error dialog in the declared dialog of the class.

How can i Achieve this.

I needed it for display purpose...now that they `JTextfield`s in the declared dialog, need to put a error dialog... at the center of the declared dialog... this is the requirement

But error dialog are visible, but behind the declared dialog, i.e on the derived `JDialog` of the class...

Thank you in advance....

Comment: uh...`Dialog.setVisible(true)`? why are you nesting dialogs anyway? -- seems like a poor design choice.

Comment: I need for display purpose...now that they textfields in the declared dialog, need to put a error dialog... at the center of the declared dialog... this is the requirement

Comment: then I'd use those made available to you by `JOptionPane`, as others have suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know exactly what you mean. However, if you want an error message dialog, why don't you just use a JOptionPane? It works very easy, e.g. like this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "message", "title", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

For layout, you can even use html in the message. Like for example:

```
<html>This went <b>wrong!</b><br>Next line</html>
```

[image]

Hope this is what you need :)

Comment: But note the screenshot.  No 'bold', since it is bold by default.  ;)  The closing `</html>` is also unnecessary (for Swing components, at least).

Comment: The bold default depends on which look&feel you take. Default Windows, Nimbus, etcetera. al don't do bold by default. But thanks for placing that screenshot, nice :)

Comment: I was thinking as I made that screenshot that the `JOptionPane` in Metal PLAF sucks big time for basic appearance, and was considering flipping to another PLAF.

Comment: Haha indeed :P I never use default Java or Metal. Just Windows or Nimbus :)

Answer (score 1):

You must show the error dialog withing the child dialog. BTW, use a [JOptionPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) to show error dialogs.